# Is it necessary to obtain NOC for completing in-service Ph.D in India?

Tags: phd, teaching, job, india

I have a problem related to my in-service Ph.D.:

- I completed my Ph. D course work in March 2017,
- joined as an assistant Professor on 16 November 2017,
- got my Ph.D registration on 14 December 2017 and
- got my Ph.D award in 2021.

I have completed my PhD without taking any study leave, but took official leave (on casual leave) from my college for attending the thesis pre-submission and final defense viva voce. So, I have not obtained an NOC from the Director of Higher and Technical Education. Now my problem is that the Directorate of higher and technical education has put my Ph.D increment on hold for not obtaining NOC for doing Ph.D. So, my question is: Is it necessary to Obtain NOC for Ph.D if the scholar has already completed the course work before joining the service?
Kindly help me in this regard. Or, can someone enlighten me with UGC norms in this regard?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid the short answer is yes (based on anecdotal evidence, hence not posting an answer). I hope you do get some relief in this case, but I'm not aware of the route you'd need to follow for that. Good luck.

Comment: When you applied for casual leave what reason did you cite?

Comment: @Shahab The reasons were clearly mentioned for Ph. D thesis submission and viva, resp.

Comment: You may apply for exemption to the directorate for obtaining NOC based on the above point and that your phd began before joining service (treating coursework is part of the phd programme). Hopefully they will respond positively.

Comment: @Shahab yes. I will request to DHTE based on your suggestion. The subject of the application would be "Request for Exemption of NOC".